# When to use dom:loaded / document.ready events

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, document-ready

When I use methods that "append" data to existing elements using prototype/jquery, is it a good practice to wrap such logic inside `document.observe("dom:loaded", foo)`/`$(document).ready(foo)` functions?

Comment: It's not only good practice, it's absolutely necessary!

Comment: All canned examples on this page (http://api.jquery.com/append/) do not seem to wrap the appending code inside `$(document).ready()`... so I am still wondering if its absolutely necessary.

Comment: Those are supposed to be very succinct examples. Real world code is always in an external file and actions like that are in dom ready callbacks. For quick hackup examples you can use the form which you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, considering referencing elements before DOM/window ready will not work unless it's the `html` element or you are injecting it after the element in the markup directly, yes it's the only way to really get it done.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>alert( document.getElementById('foo') );</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="foo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above would fail and return null.

Comment: That's understandable, but if i move the script right after the closing p tag, will that still work?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "you are injecting it after the element in the markup directly"

Answer (score 2):

Without a ready/loaded event, your code won't fire unless it's at the bottom of the page. This is because the elements don't exist when the code gets read from the `<head>` section (which executes before the body).

Try this:

```
$("body").animate({'background-color', '#ff0000'}, 2000);
```

And then try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").animate({'background-color', '#ff0000'}, 2000);
});
```

You'll see what I mean :)